# What kind of pattern should be used

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns

I was trying to make a simple question but made it trivial.
So the original setting is as follows:

```
expr = {{a}, b, {{c}, {e}}, d, {}}
```

I need that all lists are with `f` head (except outermost, including nested):

```
{f[{a}], b, f[{f[{c}], f[{e}]}], d, f[{}]}
```

What kind of pattern should I use with `/.` in this case? (I do not need `MapAt` or something that works with positions or levels).

I've tried

```
expr /. x : ({___List} | {_}) :> f@x
```

> {f[{a}], b, f[{{c}, {e}}], d, f[{}]}

Lists `{c}` and `{e}` left unattended, inspite of the fact that `expr /. x : {_} :> f@x` works with them. Some explanation of what am I doing wrong is welcome.

Thank you in advance. Excuse me those who had to read previuos version.

Comment: `Replace[expr, x_List :> f[x], {1, \[Infinity]}]` ?

Comment: @Xavier, yes, thank you, that is fine. Can you add the version with `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: @Xavier, you are right about Algohi's post but your solution (deleted) also deserves attention. Do not hide it, I've learned from it, it also might be useful for other people.

Comment: @garej Xavier has chosen `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll` quite deliberately because `Replace` gives you control over which levels of the expression are subject to replacement, whereas `ReplaceAll` does not. This control is needed here. Xavier's solution would be mine as well.

Comment: @OleksandrR., you are in general right. Nonetheless, my aim here was to understand patterns better, not only to solve the very class of problems. By the way, Xavier suggested a couple of workarounds that later decided to remove. That is pity for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(expr /. List :> Composition[f, List])[[1]]
(*{f[{a}], b, f[{f[{c}], f[{e}]}], d, f[{}]}*)
```

Comment: I like this method and [I use it myself.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5011197) +1

Answer (score 2):

```
expr /. x : {_} | {} :> f[x] /. x : {__f} :> f[x]
```

[image]